# How can I print large XML string generated by Oracle?

Tags: xml, oracle

I need something way bigger than varchar2(2000) to be able to print my generated XML.  Either recommend a better approach than dbms_output.put_line(x) or recommend a different data type to store the result and then print it.  I am an Oracle newbie and full-time job is UI development.

```
declare
    v_ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
    x varchar2(2000); -- I need something bigger than varchar2(2000)
begin
    v_ctx := DBMS_XMLGen.newContext('
        select
            baz as "Baz"
        from schema.table_with_10000_rows');
    DBMS_XMLGen.setRowsetTag(v_ctx, 'Foo');
    DBMS_XMLGen.setRowTag(v_ctx, 'Bar');
    x := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(v_ctx);
    dbms_output.put_line(x);
end;
```

Comment: I've been there before. Casting to a `BLOB`/`CLOB` seems fine in principle, but in practice we hit all manner of issues at all layers of the stack: OCI segfaults, silent truncation, character set problems. I hope someone else has a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `CLOB` if you have more than 4000 characters, and that's the data type that `getxml` returns. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1576478/266304) seems to be approaching the same issue, and shows a simple way to loop through and print in chunks, though it has a flaw - it should be using `dbms_output.put()` instead of `put_line` (edit: maybe with a terminal `dbms_output.new_line` after the loop; untested I'm afraid).

If you're doing this in SQL*Plus you can avoid `dbms_output` altogether using a [client bind variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm):

```
var x clob;

declare
    v_ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
begin
    v_ctx := DBMS_XMLGen.newContext('
        select table_name as "Baz"
        from all_tables');
    DBMS_XMLGen.setRowsetTag(v_ctx, 'Foo');
    DBMS_XMLGen.setRowTag(v_ctx, 'Bar');
    :x := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(v_ctx);
end;
/

print x
```

`x` is declared outside the PL/SQL block, and used withing it as a bind variable - note the colon in the assignment, `:x := ...`.

```
X
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Foo>
 <Bar>
  <Baz>DUAL</Baz>
 </Bar>
 <Bar>
  <Baz>SYSTE
```

By default you'll probably only see the start of the XML; you'll need to [`set long <some big number>`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699121) to see it all, and (as of 11g) you're restricted to 2GB. (I imagine you'll also want to set feedback and headings off, and maybe longchunk).

---

I'd question why you're printing it to screen like this though, rather than storing in a table. If the ultimate goal is to get it in a file, `utl_file` might be more appropriate; something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434527/266304) maybe.

Comment: Just saw your answer.  Will try today or tomorrow and likely mark as answer.  Seems like it should work.  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnZabroski - thinking about it, if you just used `dbms_output.put` in the question I linked to, you'd get no or incomplete output; I think you'd also need a `dbms_output.new_line` after the loop. You may also have buffer size issues. Are you doing this from SQL*Plus? Might have a different approach if so...

Comment: Am doing this from SQL Navigator.  I am a UI developer.  I once did DBA type stuff with SQL Server, but not Oracle.  Took an Oracle class in college 5 or 6 years ago.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking this as an answer.  What I determined is that I can access SQL*PLUS primitives for outputting information to a file, from SQL Navigator.  That dramatically simplified the task of figuring out how to serialize things, and was the linchpin to the solution.